# Positioning of divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some jquery code that makes divs apear if other divs are not empty.

I created the whole grid on my large screen and when I switch to my other monitor the positioning is all wrong.

How can I fix this?

Jquery:

```
if($("#showview2").text().length > 7 && $("#showview7").text().length > 7){
  $('.v-2-7').fadeIn(1000);
};
```

html that I'm trying to fade in:

```
<div class="v-2-7" style= "position: absolute;">
  <p>&#9482;&#9482;<br>&#9482;</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
 .v-2-7 {
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-left: 49%;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: For those interested the project is here https://github.com/Martijnkerr/branch-ed
view is view-branches-show (and css for quick and dirty fix)
and js is in assets javascripts branchshow

We did something similar in branches new and there it works perfectly.. Cant figure it out.

Comment: Can you please attach an screenshot?